# Laravel - How to store multi objects in session

Tags: php, laravel

Currently this is storing only first_name in session. I need to store some other objects of the selected user in session like level and city. How can I do that ?

```
+---------+----------+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
|    id   | username | first_name | last_name | level |  city  |
+---------+----------+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
|    1    |   john   |  John      |  Parks    |   1   | London |
|    2    |   jack   |  Jack      |  Wilson   |   2   | London |
|    3    |   sam    |  Sam       |  Neil     |   2   | London |
|    4    |   bill   |  Bill      |  Paxton   |   2   | London |
+---------+----------+------------+-----------+-------+--------+
```

**DashboardContaroller.php**

```
public function getIndex( Request $request )
    {
        $this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'first_name');
        Session::put('firstName', $request->get('first_name'));     
        return view('dashboard.index',$this->data);
    }
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
{!! Form::select('first_name', $firstNames) !!}
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**View**

```
<p>{{Session::get('firstName','default value')}}</p>
```

Comment: I'd advise storing huge amounts of data in the session.  Instead of trying to store the entire user object I'd suggest just storing the user ID and pulling the user object from the database.

Comment: I agree @GordonM Could you please show me the way

Comment: Just store the user ID (the value of the ID in your user table) and use it to look the user up in the database when you need the full details

Comment: @GordonM you mean like this ? `$this->data['firstNames'] = \DB::table('tb_users')->orderBy('first_name')->lists('first_name', 'id');`

Comment: @GordonM and please how can I pull the other objects ?

Comment: However you're doing it now!  They're stored somewhere so you must be using something to load them from where they're stored.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions contains the answer also:

```
Session::put('firstName', $request->get('first_name'));
```

in the same way you can create another session:

```
Session::put('level', $request->get('level'));
Session::put('city', $request->get('city'));
```

Comment: Yes I need an array @Robin

Answer (score 1):

Here you can insert an array:

```
$items = collect([
    [
        'firstname' => $request->get('first_name')
    ], [
        'firstname' => $request->get('first_name')
    ], [
        'firstname' => $request->get('first_name')
    ]
]);

foreach(Session::get('firstName') as $firstName) {
    $items[] = $firstName; //past the old items in the array.
}

Session::push('users', $items);
```

Now you can use:

```
<p>
    @foreach(Session::get('firstName',[]) as $users)
        {{ $user['firstname'] }}
    @endforeach
</p>
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thank you. I am getting error **Undefined variable: user**

Comment: I think you got only the `firstname` from the request, if you got the `user_id` you can get the user object and past it in the array! @Selim

Comment: Getting this error now **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Answer (score 0):

To store data in the session, you will typically use the request instance's put method or the global session helper. Just send an array of data:

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put(['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2']);

// Via the global "session" helper...
session(['key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2']);
```